# Separar cadena de un value del input y hacer el envío de las dos partes separadas

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Supongamos que tengo este formulario html

```
<form id="miForm" name="miForm" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input id="cedula" name="cedula" type="text" placeholder="Cedula de Identidad"/>
</form>
```

Estoy utilizando este Script el cual hace que al ingresar numeros la cadena quedé de esta manera:
12.345.678-5, en resumen le agrega los puntos y le agrega el guion, por ejemplo si ingreso: `123456784` quedaría `12.345.678-5`

```
document.getElementById('cedula').addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
    let value = this.value.replace(/\./g, '').replace('-', '');
        
    if (value.match(/^(\d{2})(\d{3}){2}(\w{1})$/)) {
        value = value.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\w{1})$/, '$1.$2.$3-$4');
    }
    else if (value.match(/^(\d)(\d{3}){2}(\w{0,1})$/)) {
        value = value.replace(/^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\w{0,1})$/, '$1.$2.$3-$4');
    }
    else if (value.match(/^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{0,2})$/)) {
        value = value.replace(/^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{0,2})$/, '$1.$2.$3');
    }
    else if (value.match(/^(\d)(\d{0,2})$/)) {
        value = value.replace(/^(\d)(\d{0,2})$/, '$1.$2');
    }
    this.value = value;
});
```

Lo que necesito es que guarde lo que está antes y después del guión.
Por ejemplo:

```
cedula: "12345678"
dv: "5"
```

Y poder enviarlo por método POST con Javascript
Este es mi archivo js donde obtengo los datos del formulario y el envio
Aquí supongo que debo en vez de obtener el formulario completo, debería obtenerlo por cada input, pero no se como realizar aquello.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {

    var miForm = document.getElementById('miForm');
    miForm.onsubmit = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        var jsonData = {};
        for (var [k, v] of formData) {
            jsonData[k] = v
        }
        
        sendData_Persona();

        function sendData_Persona() {
            const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // Bind the FormData object and the form element
            // El Replace lo utilizo para quitarle los . y - que anteriormente le agregué.
            const FD = (  JSON.stringify(jsonData).replace(/[\.-]+/g, "") );

            // Set up our request
            XHR.open( "POST", "/api/v1/register_person" );

            // The data sent is what the user provided in the form
            XHR.send( FD );
            
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que debe hacer es que en su función `onsubmit` en vez de agarrar todo el form vamos a crear el `FormData` manualmente, quedando así *(su backend va a recibir las 2 propiedades por separado)*:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {

    var miForm = document.getElementById('miForm');
    miForm.onsubmit = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var str = document.getElementById('cedula').value; // aprovechamos ya que tiene el valor en formato: 12.345.678-5
        var formData = new FormData();
        // var jsonData = {};
        var cedula = str.split('-')[0].replace(/\./g, '');
        var dv = str.split('-')[1];
        formData.append("cedula", cedula);
        formData.append("dv", dv);
        // jsonData.cedula = cedula;
        // jsonData.dv = dv;

        const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

        XHR.open( "POST", "/api/v1/register_person" );

        XHR.send( formData );
        // XHR.send( JSON.stringify(jsonData) );
            
    }
});
```

PD: También le quiero recomendar que mejor envíe el `12.345.678-5` tal cual al backend y en el backend lo valide y lo separe como lo requiere cedula=`12345678` y dv=`5`

Comment: Hola gracias por tu tiempo y respuesta, recibo por separado las dos propiedades pero necesito pasarlas como un objeto Json

Comment: @Javier le acabo de editar la respuesta y le dejé en comentado la parte de enviar un json string al backend

Comment: Ahora si! Funciona a la perfección, muchas gracias! PD: en cuanto al tema del backend, yo no lo toco, yo estoy a cargo del front en este proyecto

Comment: Super, me alegra haber ayudado! @Javier